# Linker fails building library with CMake

Tags: cmake, makefile, lua, static-libraries

I'm trying to build LUAGLM (from https://github.com/gottfriedleibniz/lua) to bind GLM library to give access in Lua using cmake. When i build, the building completes ok but the linker does not giving error:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [glm.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/glm.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Above these lines there is a very long list starting with:

```
[ 10%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/liblua.dir/onelua.c.o
[ 20%] Linking CXX shared library liblua54.dylib
[ 20%] Built target liblua
[ 30%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/liblua_static.dir/onelua.c.o
[ 40%] Linking CXX static library liblua54_static.a
[ 40%] Built target liblua_static
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/lua.dir/lua.c.o
[ 60%] Linking CXX executable lua
[ 60%] Built target lua
[ 70%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/luac.dir/onelua.c.o
[ 80%] Linking CXX executable luac
[ 80%] Built target luac
[ 90%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/glm.dir/libs/glm_binding/lglmlib.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX shared module glm.so
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "glm_pushmat(lua_State*, glmMatrix const&)", referenced from:
      glm_mat_add(lua_State*) in lglmlib.cpp.o
      glm_mat_sub(lua_State*) in lglmlib.cpp.o
      glm_mat_mul(lua_State*) in lglmlib.cpp.o
      glm_mat_negate(lua_State*) in lglmlib.cpp.o
      glm_mix(lua_State*) in lglmlib.cpp.o
      glm_saturation(lua_State*) in lglmlib.cpp.o
      glm_orthonormalize(lua_State*) in lglmlib.cpp.o
      ...
```

I'm on MacOS Intel (i386-apple-darwin11.3.0)

Not sure where to go next, do I need to edit the CMakeList somehow?

Any help much appreciated

EDIT:

The cmake error log contains the following :

```
Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed. Compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc Build flags: Id flags:

The output was: 1 ld: library not found for -lSystem clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed. Compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ Build flags: Id flags:

The output was: 1 ld: library not found for -lc++ clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Above the line `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64` it should be error lines describing which exact symbols a not found. For being able to help you we need to see that lines. If there are too many of such lines, make sure to add at least the **first** such line into the question post.

Comment: ok looking for them now

Comment: In the terminal output i just have list of references: 3 lines above are :   "_luaglm_vec2", referenced from:
      luaglm_lib in lglmlib.cpp.o
  "_luaglm_vec3", referenced from:
      luaglm_lib in lglmlib.cpp.o
  "_luaglm_vec4", referenced from:
      luaglm_lib in lglmlib.cpp.o

Comment: will check the log file

Comment: @Tsyvarev Hopefully the edit is what is needed? Thanks

Comment: Please, add to the **question post** the **error messages** about missed symbols. Why do you ever look into `CMakeError.log`? CMake notes this file only in case of **configuration** errors, and even in case of these errors content of that file is usually not useful.

Comment: I thought it might be useful (very new to cmake!). The lines above are very long, such that it seems maybe all symbols are undefined, I put the first few.

Comment: Do not use **blockquote** formatting for the error messages: this formatting doesn't preserve newlines, so the messages become harder to read and understand. Instead, use **code formatting**.

Comment: Have you considered raising the issue with the project's development team?  Because the two most likely possibilities are that you're doing something wrong for the project or that the project is buggy, and both of these will be most easily addressed by someone very familiar with the project.

Comment: Thanks, I considered it but didn't know how to. Plus i wanted to be sure it wasnt a basic error on my part, since i'm very new to cmake

Comment: What was the exact cmake command you executed? LUA has quite a few configuration values one can pass to cmake. Maybe you did something wrong there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a bug in the CMakeList.txt because the library-list for the glm.so module does not contain the liblua.

If you apply the following patch

```
diff --git a/CMakeLists.txt b/CMakeLists.txt
index 8cf8a1a6..6eda2a17 100644
--- a/CMakeLists.txt
+++ b/CMakeLists.txt
@@ -940,7 +940,7 @@ ENDIF()
 
 ADD_LIBRARY(glm MODULE ${SRC_LIBGLM})
 TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(glm PRIVATE ${INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES})
-TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(glm PRIVATE ${LIBS})
+TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(glm PRIVATE ${LIBS} liblua_static)
 IF( LUA_BUILD_AS_DLL )
   TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(glm PUBLIC ${interpretor_target})
   TARGET_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS(glm PRIVATE LUA_BUILD_AS_DLL)
```

to the freshly cloned repository and then do (inside the cloned repository):

```
git submodule update --init
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DONE_LUA=ON ..
make
```

you should find the files glm.so, lua and luac in your build directory. At least that worked on my Intel MacBook.

Using liblua_static in the CMakeList.txt for the library glm makes sure, that the resulting glm.so does not need the liblua dynamic library but contains the required code statically. That avoids problems when loading glm.so and the liblua library not being in the library path.

I opened an issue in the GitHub repository for it. So hopefully it will get fixed for everybody soon.

Comment: Great, thanks for the advice, going to try this later

Comment: It worked  @Frank ! I now have another problem (debugging my code hangs when i try to require the glm.so) but the question was answered. Was hoping to give you a bounty of 50 but since i already raised one minimum new bounty is 200.

Comment: @gwizardry I changed my answer to use liblua_static instead of liblua in the link-library definition patch for the library glm.so and added a paragraph about that in the text. I presume your problem comes from liblua54.dylib not being found in your library path when loading glm.so . With the change in linking glm.so it won't need liblua54.dylib any longer. You can - by the way - check, what library glm.so needs by using the command `otool -L glm.so`

Answer (score -1):

Usually it'll be something like `-lYourLibrary not found`, if `-lSystem` for example is not found, try adding it to your CMakeLists.

Are you still having the issue?

Comment: This is not an answer. It should've been a comment. If you do not have sufficient reputation to comment, please refrain from using *answers* for *commenting*.

Comment: I don't have sufficient rep, sorry. Though I was actually trying to help unlike the other people commenting.

Comment: Your effort is very much appreciated! Nonetheless, there are reasons why you first need to have sufficient reputation in order to comment. It was not chosen at random. Please do not try to bypass those restrictions. As for others trying to help, I believe that asking for clarifications and giving feedback regarding the tools used to provide the question's text is helping.